# Changing legend properties in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am relatively new to ggplot2 and was wondering if there was a simple way to change legend plots. I have added a dummy variable (AEmpty in the example below) to my dataframe that accounts for spacing and bar widths for uneven number of factors after a previous answer [Control column widths in a ggplot2 graph with a series and inconsistent data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28890227/control-column-widths-in-a-ggplot2-graph-with-a-series-and-inconsistent-data/28904303#28904303). This seemed like the easiest way - although a comment or answer potentially addressing an alternative way is welcome!

So in the example below, I get a plot output that looks like this. 
[image]

My questions are (1) Is there a way to select the grey scale from 'after', thus maximising color contrast between the bars displayed? (2) In the legend, how can I remove AEmpty? I saw a similar question here [How do I manually change the key labels in a legend in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323191/how-do-i-manually-change-the-key-labels-in-a-legend-in-ggplot2)  but the answers here do not work because I have already applied a fill function elsewhere and scale_fill_discrete does not work.

Also if anyone would know of an easier way to scale the x-axis factors, thus eliminating the need for this 'dummy' variable, an answer would be greatly appreciated. Ultimately, the desired output is a barplot whereby each bar has equal width and each 'site' on the x-axis are equally spaced apart, with only relevant factors being displayed in the key.

```
library(ggplot2)
#Create data
when <- as.factor(c(rep(c("Before","After"),each = 3),
      rep("During", 2),"AEmpty"))
site <- as.factor(c(rep(c("a","b","c"), 2),
      "b","a","c"))
mean <- c(6,4.5,4.5,1.75,3.25,2.5,3,0,0)
std_error <- c(2.31,1.04,0.5,0.63,1.70,1.32,1.53,NA,NA)
df <- data.frame(when,site,mean,std_error)
#Plot 
limits <- aes(ymax = mean + std_error, ymin=mean-std_error)
g <- ggplot(df, aes(site,mean,fill=when)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) + geom_errorbar(limits, width = 0.25, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) + scale_fill_grey()
g
```

Comment: Provide simple reproducible example or part of your dataset

Comment: Change the creation of your dummies to: `summarised_df <- rbind(summarised_df,c("During","a",NA,NA),
                       c("During","c",NA,NA))`

Comment: The example data has been edited and is hopefully more clear now thank you.

Comment: About the colors: have a look at `scale_fill_manual()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by: "I have already applied a fill function elsewhere". Since `fill` can appear just once per graph, you could incorporate `breaks` and `labels` into your "other fill function", which you are not displaying here.

The code below does what you want for the example you provided:

```
library(ggplot2)
# Create data
when <- as.factor(c(rep(c("Before","After"),each = 3),
                    rep("During", 2),"AEmpty"))
site <- as.factor(c(rep(c("a","b","c"), 2),
                    "b","a","c"))
mean <- c(6,4.5,4.5,1.75,3.25,2.5,3,0,0)
std_error <- c(2.31,1.04,0.5,0.63,1.70,1.32,1.53,NA,NA)
df <- data.frame(when,site,mean,std_error)

# Plot 
limits <- aes(ymax = mean + std_error, ymin=mean-std_error)

ggplot(df, aes(site,mean,fill=when)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(limits, width = 0.25, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("AEmpty" = "grey1",
                               "After" = "grey15",
                               "Before" = "grey55",
                               "During" = "grey75"),
                    breaks = c("After", "Before", "During"),
                    labels = c("After", "Before", "During"))
```

[image]

To choose shades of grey, consult [this list of R-colours](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~tzheng/files/Rcolor.pdf).