# scale_fill_discrete does not change label names

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I've got a problem when trying to change the name of the labels in the legend of a plot using **ggplot**.

I come to read some tutorials on the topic in [Cookbook for R](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_%28ggplot2%29/) and questions on the same topic in this forum ([How do I manually change the key labels in a legend in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323191/how-do-i-manually-change-the-key-labels-in-a-legend-in-ggplot2)), and some more. The reason I write this is because I cannot understand what is going on with my **ggplot** function that makes **scale_fill_discrete ()** don't work while in other examples it does.

My data frame is something like:

```
           x w t
1  0.8972208 A 0
2  0.8312684 A 1
3  0.7504638 A 2
4  0.6563472 A 3
5  0.5764883 A 4
6  0.5224609 A 5
7  0.8972208 B 0
8  0.8456315 B 1
9  0.7674353 B 2
10 0.6689723 B 3
11 0.6114414 B 4
12 0.5381668 B 5
13 0.8983253 C 0
14 0.7878405 C 1
15 0.6955420 C 2
16 0.6179749 C 3
17 0.5524141 C 4
18 0.4966967 C 5
```

As far as I know, sorting factors in the legend is a very difficult task using **ggplot**, and that's the reason why they are ordered alphabetically in the dataframe (`factor w`). However the real names should be something different ,like: "O", "R" and "N.

The **ggplot** function I'm ussing is:

```
ggplot (data = eso3, aes (x=t, y = x, colour = w, linetype = w, shape= w))
  +geom_line()
  +geom_point()
  +scale_linetype_manual("LEGEND TITLE",values =c("solid","solid","dashed","dashed","dotted","dotted"))
  +scale_colour_manual("LEGEND TITLE",values=c("black","black","darkgray","darkgray","dimgray","dimgray"))
  +scale_shape_manual("LEGEND TITLE",values=c(19,15,19,15,19,15))
  +scale_y_continuous("Y LABEL",limits=c(0.0,1.0))
  +theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle=0))
  +scale_fill_discrete("LEGEND TITLE",breaks=c("A","B","C"),labels=c("O","R","N"))
  +ggtitle("MAIN TITLE")
  +theme_bw()
```

I know function **scale_fill_discrete** should change `("A","B","C")` to `("O","R","N")`. Why it does not work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you used the `colour`, `linetype` and `shape` but not `fill`, you have to integrate the new labeles with the `scale_xxx_manual()`calls like :

```
ggplot (data = eso3, aes (x=t, y = x, colour = w, linetype = w, shape= w))+
geom_line()+
geom_point()+
scale_linetype_manual("LEGEND TITLE",values =c("solid","solid","dashed","dashed","dotted","dotted"),breaks=c("A", "B", "C"), labels=c("O","R","N"))+
scale_colour_manual("LEGEND TITLE",values=c("black","black","darkgray","darkgray","dimgray","dimgray"),breaks=c("A", "B", "C"), labels=c("O","R","N"))+
scale_shape_manual("LEGEND TITLE",values=c(19,15,19,15,19,15),breaks=c("A", "B", "C"), labels=c("O","R","N"))+
scale_y_continuous("Y LABEL",limits=c(0.0,1.0))+
theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle=0))+
ggtitle("MAIN TITLE")+
theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Very constructive answer, thank you very much! It solves the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You did not use the fill parameter in your ggplot(..) function, so you cannot use scale_fill_discrete().

Use scale_colour_discrete(), scale_linetype_discrete(), or scale_shape_discrete() depending on which legend you want to change. Most mentions I've seen of how to change labels leverage scale_fill_discrete but neglect to mention that is only if you have use the fill parameter.