# How to change legend of facet_grid?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I used R and ggplot to do a small-multiple graph.

```
ggplot(data=datatest,aes(x=Percentage,y=Accuracy,group=interaction(Classifiers, Feature), color=interaction(Classifiers, Feature)))+geom_line()+facet_grid(OS ~ Dataset)
```

The graph I got is:
[image]

How can I remove change the legend, for example, I want to change interaction(Classifiers,Feature) to just 'Approaches', and also, how to change like SVM.Ngram, LG.WE, SVM.WE to just 'approach1','approach2', and 'approach3'.

Comment: Please share your data using `dput()`. [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: One possibility for the legend is to edit your data like `datatest$Approaches=interaction(datatest$Classifiers, datatest$Feature)` then use that in the plot.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323191/how-do-i-manually-change-the-key-labels-in-a-legend-in-ggplot2?noredirect=1&lq=1) shows how to change group labels in your legend, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622421/how-to-change-legend-title-in-ggplot) shows how to change the legend title.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
tbl <- c(
  SVM.Ngram = "approach1",
  LG.WE = "approach2",
  SVM.WE = "approach3"
)
ggplot(data=datatest,
  aes(x=Percentage,y=Accuracy,group=interaction(Classifiers, Feature), color=interaction(Classifiers, Feature))) + 
  geom_line() +
  labs(color = "Approaches") + 
  facet_grid(OS ~ Dataset, labeller = labeller(tbl)
)
```

This is from http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/labeller.html - if you check there, it gives more options you might be interested in.

Comment: I tried +labs(group='Approaches'), it doesn't work, still showing interaction(Classifiers,Feature)

Comment: Try this - it's the color that's being affected in the legend - I wasn't looking closely enough.

Comment: thx,actually,i used the dumb way. i changed my data file manually and combine the classifiers and feature as one column.