# Change text/labels ggplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, choropleth

I believe this question is slightly different than similar ones asked on here before because of the use of `scale_fill_brewer(`.  I'm working on a choropleth similar to this one https://gist.github.com/233134

That looks like this:

[image: Chloropleth]

and the legend like:

[image: legend]

I like it but want to change the labels on the legend from cut looking labels ie **(2, 4]** to something more friendly like '**2% to 4%**' or '**2% - 4%**'.  I've seen elsewhere it;s easy to change the labels inside of scale_... as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339953/how-to-add-custom-series-labels-to-a-legend-in-rs-ggplot).  I can't seem to figure out where to put the labels= argument.  I of course could re code `choropleth$rate_d` but that seems to be inefficient.  Where should I put the argument `labels=c(A, B, C, D...)`?

**Here's the piece of the code of interest (for the full code use the link above)**

```
choropleth$rate_d <- cut(choropleth$rate, breaks = c(seq(0, 10, by = 2), 35))

# Once you have the data in the right format, recreating the plot is straight
# forward.

ggplot(choropleth, aes(long, lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = rate_d), colour = alpha("white", 1/2), size = 0.2) + 
  geom_polygon(data = state_df, colour = "white", fill = NA) +
  scale_fill_brewer(pal = "PuRd")
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

***EDIT:  USing DWin's method (should have posted this error as this is what I ran up against before)***

```
> ggplot(choropleth, aes(long, lat, group = group)) +
+   geom_polygon(aes(fill = rate_d), colour = alpha("white", 1/2), size = 0.2) + 
+   geom_polygon(data = state_df, colour = "white", fill = NA) +
+   scale_fill_brewer(pal = "PuRd", labels = lev4)
Error: Labels can only be specified in conjunction with breaks
```

Comment: You're too fast. I saw the error and fixed it. I got a slightly more informative message: "Error: Labels and breaks must be same length"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Besides adding a modified version of the levels, you also need to set the 'breaks' parameter to `scale_fill_brewer`:

```
lev = levels(rate_d)  # used (2, 4] as test case
 lev2 <- gsub("\\,", "% to ", lev)
 lev3 <- gsub("\\]$", "%", lev2)
 lev3
[1] "(2% to 4%"
lev4 <- gsub("\\(|\\)", "", lev3)
 lev4
[1] "2% to 4%"

ggplot(choropleth, aes(long, lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = rate_d), colour = alpha("white", 1/2), size = 0.2) + 
  geom_polygon(data = state_df, colour = "white", fill = NA) +
  scale_fill_brewer(pal = "PuRd", labels = lev4, , breaks=seq(0, 10, by = 2) )
```

Comment: I tried it and get the error I was getting before (nice use of gsub though).  I edited my post to reflect this error.

Comment: After the edits it works perfect.  Thanks DWin.  It was the breaks!  Duh that's what the error said.  I just didn't know what to do with it.

Comment: @TylerRinker I realise this is slightly annoying behaviour, but I was worried people might mis-set the labels and they'd end up out of alignment with the breaks.